# Why there is no cpufreq under /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/?

Tags: linux, cpu, centos, kernel

Why there is no cpufreq under /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/?

I want to read current cpu frequency but I didn't find cpufreq under `/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/`.

In kernel I enabled CONFIG_CPU_FREQ.

```
$ cat /boot/config-3.10.0-957.el7.x86_64 |grep CONFIG_CPU_FREQ
CONFIG_CPU_FREQ=y
CONFIG_CPU_FREQ_GOV_COMMON=y
CONFIG_CPU_FREQ_STAT=m
CONFIG_CPU_FREQ_STAT_DETAILS=y
# CONFIG_CPU_FREQ_DEFAULT_GOV_PERFORMANCE is not set
# CONFIG_CPU_FREQ_DEFAULT_GOV_USERSPACE is not set
CONFIG_CPU_FREQ_DEFAULT_GOV_ONDEMAND=y
# CONFIG_CPU_FREQ_DEFAULT_GOV_CONSERVATIVE is not set
CONFIG_CPU_FREQ_GOV_PERFORMANCE=y
CONFIG_CPU_FREQ_GOV_POWERSAVE=y
CONFIG_CPU_FREQ_GOV_USERSPACE=y
CONFIG_CPU_FREQ_GOV_ONDEMAND=y
CONFIG_CPU_FREQ_GOV_CONSERVATIVE=y
```

OS:`CentOS Linux release 7.6.1810 (Core)`

CPU:`Intel(R) Xeon(R) Gold 6248R CPU @ 3.00GHz`

Comment: That's just the overall subsystem, but do you have any of the actual frequency-scaling drivers enabled? Do you have `CONFIG_X86_INTEL_PSTATE` and `CONFIG_X86_ACPI_CPUFREQ`?

Answer (score 1):

Please go into the BIOS and confirm that CPC (Collaborative Power Control) is disabled. When CPC is disabled intel_pstate will be used instead by the operating system to control power management.